# Update posted columns only

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with rest API in CodeIgniter
I am working with update API so I want to update only those columns/fields which I sent via postman,
for example, if I sent only `first_name` and `last_name` then only these columns should be updated not all columns,
but current code updating all columns, Here is my code where I am wrong?

```
    public function update_userrecords()
    {

    $add_data['user_id'] = ($this->input->post('user_id') && !empty($this->input->post('user_id'))) ? $this->input->post('user_id') : NULL;

    $add_data['first_name'] = ($this->input->post('first_name') && !empty($this->input->post('first_name'))) ? $this->input->post('first_name') : NULL;

    $add_data['last_name'] = ($this->input->post('last_name') && !empty($this->input->post('last_name'))) ? $this->input->post('last_name') : NULL;

    $add_data['password'] = ($this->input->post('password') && !empty($this->input->post('password'))) ? $this->input->post('password') : NULL;


    $t=time();

    $data = array(
    'first_name'=>$add_data['first_name'],
    'last_name'=>$add_data['last_name'],
    'password'=>md5($add_data['password']),
    'updated_on'=>$t,
    );

    $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);

    }
```

Comment: use set() method

Comment: @DevsiOdedra : How ?please explain

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
 $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->update('users');

Comment: @DanishAli : current code/query updating all records,means if i not post first_name then first_name become null (removing existing value of column in mysql)

Comment: Yes. Because you are giving null if the value does not exist. So what you want to do?

Comment: Just check if a parameter is posted before adding it to the array at all. Don't add non posted values at all. (non codeigniter example since I don't know CI that well): `$data = []; if (array_key_exists('first_name', $_POST)) {  $data['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name']; }` and so on.

Comment: use if(!empty(your-value)){ // Add in an array}

Comment: **Warning** Never store passwords in clear text!. Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this way**

Set you input field in new array and update that array. I have added one field in `$insert_data`. you can add as much you want.

```
public function update_userrecords()
 {
     $add_data['user_id'] = ($this->input->post('user_id') && !empty($this->input->post('user_id'))) ? $this->input->post('user_id') : NULL;

     $insert_data = [];



    if($this->input->post('first_name') && !empty($this->input->post('first_name'))) {
        $insert_data['first_name'] = $this->input->post('user_id');
    }


    $t=time();


    $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
    $this->db->update('users', $insert_data);

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need both `if ($value && !empty($value))`. Just do `if (!empty($value))`. Also, this only works as long as no column is  allowed to be null, 0, empty string or any other value that `empty()` considers to be empty.